# check tthe set interval value is cleared or not

Tags: jquery

Is there any possible way to check the setInterval value is cleared or not

```
var interval = setInterval(function () {
      getTestStatus(len, $('#server').val());
    }, 20000);
```

am calling   `clearInterval(interval);` in another place

I want to check if set interval is cleared or not?how it is possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can set interval to null after clearing and put check on null.

Set interval to null

```
clearInterval(interval);
interval = null;
```

Checking if interval is clear

```
if(interval != null){}
```

Comment: how i set in below case `vmstart = setInterval(function () {
      $.get('/getVMstatus', function (data) {
        if (data != "") {
          clearInterval(vmstart);
vmstart ="ssss";
          $("#vmstart").show();
          $("#vmstart").html(data[0].ip)+".....</br>";
          $.post('/deleteReport', function (data) {});
        }
      });
    }, 1000);`